# Where to test default method implementation of superclass

Tags: java, testing, design-patterns

I have fallowing classes:

Parent.java

```
interface Parent{
    void method1();

    default void method2(){
       //some default impl
    }
}
```

ChildOne.java

```
class ChildOne implements Parent{
    @Override
    void method1(){
        //ChildOne specific implementation
    }
}
```

ChildTwo.java

```
class ChildTwo implements Parent{
    @Override
    void method1(){
        //ChildTwo specific implementation
    }
}
```

Question is: where I should put a method 2 test? I know that for unit tests I should test concrete implementation so ChildOne and ChildTwo but when I have the same implementation of method2 I don't want to duplicate my test for it. However putting it into one of these classes don't seems to be good either.

Ofc, question is the same for abstract class with default implementation instead of interface.

Comment: Well, create a ParentTest class, and write your test there, by creating a custom subclass instance in the test, that allows testing the default method.

Comment: What @JBNizet said. Create a test for `Parent` that uses an implementation `private` to the test so you can guarantee you are testing the behaviour of `Parent#method2` rather than anything else.

Comment: So obvious... why I didn't think about this... Guys, create a answers from your comment. I will accept it in next 8 minutes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create a `ParentTest` class, and write your test there, by creating a custom subclass instance in the test (private to the test), that allows testing the default method.